# Why is mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair returning an error?

Tags: c, rsa, mbedtls

I'm parsing an RSA private key from a buffer with `mbedtls_pk_parse_key()`, which returns 0.  I then call `mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair()` and it returns -20096 (which I believe corresponds to `MBEDTLS_ERR_ECP_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE)`.

I'm building something similar to the following code using the XDK Workbench:

```
  mbedtls_mpi r, s;
  mbedtls_pk_context pk;
  mbedtls_ecdsa_context ecdsa_sign;

  mbedtls_mpi_init(&r);
  mbedtls_mpi_init(&s);
  mbedtls_pk_init(&pk);
  mbedtls_ecdsa_init(&ecdsa_sign);

  int ret = mbedtls_pk_parse_key(&pk,  priv_key, strlen(priv_key) + 1, NULL, 0);
  /* Returns 0 */

  ret = mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair(&ecdsa_sign, pk.pk_ctx);
  /* Returns -20096 */
```

When I look at the implementation of `mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair()`, I see that `pk.pk_ctx` is treated as an `mbedtls_ecp_keypair`.  The `grp` member of the `mbedtls_ecp_keypair` has an `id` member of zero, which corresponds to `MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_NONE`. Am I passing the wrong thing to `mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `mbedtls_ecdsa_from_keypair()` doesn't seem to work with an RSA key.  I switched to an EC private key (`secp256r1` to be exact) and it began working properly.